# 403 Forbidden ERROR with WebClient request

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I understand this is a quite frequently asked question and also have many proposals and solutions. However, I tried almost all of them but still cannot fix this issue from my side, even with Fiddler's http request headers configured. I am not sure whether this is a specific one or I missed something else important. So I asked this question again, hope could get any further support from you. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code used with the link:

```
  Dim WC As New System.Net.WebClient
        'WC.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705Wink")
        WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "Text/ html, Application / xhtml + Xml, Application / Xml;q=0.9, Image / webp, Image / apng,*/*;q=0.8")
        WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36")
        WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br")
        WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8")
        'WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "true")
        WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Host, "www.fda.gov")

        'WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "")
        'WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength, "")

        Dim strURL As String = "https://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Guidances/UCM227351.pdf"
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        WC.DownloadFile(strURL, "1.pdf")
```

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated!

Thanks again!

Stanley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, any time you use .net to make a web request you should catch exceptions, specifically of the webexception type.  This will let you get the response from the server.  See below.

```
  Dim strURL As String = "https://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Guidances/UCM227351.pdf"

  Try
     WC.DownloadFile(strURL, "1.pdf")
  Catch ex As Net.WebException

     If ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim response = ex.Response
        Dim dataStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream
        Dim reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim errorDetails As String = reader.ReadToEnd

        '  do something with errorDetails

     End If

  End Try
```

I was curious so I did the same for your URL, and found that it returns this helpful information.

> This page cannot be displayed.  We're sorry for any inconvenience this issue has caused.  Make sure you are using a client that supports TLS.1.2.

To correct the error please add this code before your web request.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this instruction. Although there was a new issue raised at the beginning, that TLS12 was not supported with .NET 4.0, however, it's fixed once it's upgraded to .NET 4.5. Everything works perfect now.

Comment: The following link introduced some workarounds for the TLS issues. https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/.

Comment: If using .net 4.0 you can add this to force TLS1.2

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`